# Dijit multiple widgets not parsed when row deleted with dGrid (dgrid.io)

Tags: dojo, dgrid

I use dGrid 0.4.1-dev (dgrid.io) with a custom formatter (I have tried with custom renderer) to return **raw HTMLthat contains Dijit widgets** , during the page load, all widgets has been parsed correctly but it's totally broken when sort, paginate or scroll (OnDemandGrid).

In my example, I use Tooltip widget on icons (**declarative mode**, see bottom "Returned HTML for the cell").

### On page load:

[image]

### After scroll,sort, paginate...:

[image]

### Returned HTML for the cell (by the formatter):

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/Tooltip" id="comxDynElement_101_dijit_1" data-dojo-props="connectId:'comxDynElement_101',position:['above']">Dupliquer cette facture</div><a href="..." id="comxDynElement_101"><i class="fa fa-clone"></i></a>
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/Tooltip" id="comxDynElement_102_dijit_1" data-dojo-props="connectId:'comxDynElement_102',position:['above']">Télécharger cette facture</div><a id="comxDynElement_102" href="..."><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i></a>
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/Tooltip" id="comxDynElement_103_dijit_1" data-dojo-props="connectId:'comxDynElement_103',position:['above']">Voir cette facture</div><a id="comxDynElement_103" href="..."><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
```

### My formatter:

```
function (item) {
     return item;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The widgets are being build and started on page load by the [Dojo Parser](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/parser.html). When new declarative html is added to your page after the page is already loaded, these widgets are not automatically parsed. You need to do that manually.

For example, it should be possible to call the parser manually in a `renderRow` function of your grid. An example can be found [here](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/master/doc/components/core-components/OnDemandList-and-OnDemandGrid.md).

So the following code could work:

```
   require([
        'dgrid/OnDemandList',
        'dojo/parser'
    ], function (OnDemandList,parser) {
        var list = new OnDemandList({
            collection: myStore, // a dstore collection
            renderRow: function (object, options) {
                var div = document.createElement('div');
                div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(object.myField));
                // only 'parse' new row, not whole document again.
                parser.parse(div);
                return div;
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Hi :) Yes you are right but not working when user sort columns. I use: aspect.before(myGrid, 'renderRow', function(){ parser.parse(rowElement); });